# Need to create shared data in virtual memory in vxWorks

Tags: vxworks

We want to create shared data in the virtual memory area in vxWorks. We got some information that we need to use vmLib API for mapping virtual memory to our application. But we dont know much about how to use this. If anybody has used the same or related thing please tell me how to solve the issue.

Comment: what version of vxworks?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VxWorks 6.x, then you can simply use the Shared Data facility present in the OS.  Look at the sdLib documentation for the details, but it has a very simple interface.